# how can I solve edittext recursion problem?

Tags: kotlin, recursion, android-textinputedittext

I was trying to implement live typeface change's in the  `edittextview`
based on markdown syntax
and the first code I do was

```kotlin
my_edit_text_view.text = makeMDStyleSpannable(my_edit_text_view.text)//returns spannableString
```

but no luck since it is not invoking every time when text is changed

so I gave another try which is creating listener and testing things are working properly before I jump

```kotlin
my_edit_text_view.text = doOnTextChanged { it, start, count,after ->
            if (it != null) {
                if(it.isNotEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(this, (makeMDStyleSpannable(it)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     
                }else if(it.isNullOrEmpty()){

                }

            }
        }
```

as [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkJsL.jpg) it worked on another TOAST

However, here's the real recurring happened

```kotlin
my_edit_text_view.text = doOnTextChanged { it, start, count,after ->
            if (it != null) {
                if(it.isNotEmpty()){
                   my_edit_text_view.text = (makeMDStyleSpannable(it)
                }else if(it.isNullOrEmpty()){

                }

            }
        }
```

umm, what actually happening is while there is external text change(keyboard) on the `edittext` it calls `makeMDStyleSpannable` and this apply internal change then again and again it will call `doOnTextChanged`, Finally crashes.
How could I solve this problem?

```
keyboard(onText added[external]) => startThelistner => makeMDStyleSpannable[in]
                                     /\                    ||
                                     ||=====[infinite]=======
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by adding a boolean to check if text is changed by user or the code.

```
val shouldIgnoreChange = false
my_edit_text_view.text = doOnTextChanged { it, start, count,after ->
        if (it != null) {
            if(it.isNotEmpty()){
               if(!shouldIgnoreChange){
                   shouldIgnoreChange = true
                   my_edit_text_view.text = (makeMDStyleSpannable(it)
                   shouldIgnoreChange = false
               }
            }else if(it.isNullOrEmpty()){

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, it worked but while typing it goes from right to left like ( <=) and also its recreating keyboard every time l.e [if i toggle numeric keyboard it create new keyboard with alphabet in every-time while typing] so if i want to type numeric letter I need to toggle it from the alphabet which is bit hard

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MZdUJJkTIjGRwWeDsUhb1_eMdxDTCflM/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: do you change `my_edit_text_view` in any other place?

Comment: no, not yet i just tried commenting                                                                                            
                  
                   my_edit_text_view.text = (makeMDStyleSpannable(it)
 and it worked properly without formatting the text https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N0TDheEDJY_RMUiaz-uVQQIyg7QBFaOs/view